# Is there a way to add the Visual Studio 2022 hot reload button to Rider?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2022, rider, hot-reload, rider-plugin

Recently, I have decided to try moving to Rider from Visual Studio 2022 for the .NET API and Winforms Development.
Everything looks great so far, but I have one feature missing - Hot Reload Button.
[image: Hot reload button in Visual Studio 2022]

In Visual Studio, this button click animation was "Confirming" that the changes were made, and in Rider I'm not sure if anything has changed.

Can I somehow add it to Rider as the button?

I've found the hotkeys for the hot reload in Rider, but I'd like to get some kind of the notification that "The changes have been applied".

The button would be the perfect solution, but anything else, which can be recognized as the Confirmation, would be ok aswell.

Comment: MS uses the VS Debugging experience as the wedge to drive freeloader users of VS Code into paying $2,200/yr for VS Enterprise. So, I doubt it.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Hot_Reload.html#Make_changes_when_debugging seems to indicate a banner should appear in your editor?

Comment: If you believe that's something Rider should have, talk to JetBrains, not here, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RIDER

Comment: @donatellony Hi, you can take a look of my answer. :)

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT thank you very much! That's what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, this feature should be enabled by default since Rider 2021.3:

[What’s New in Rider 2021.3](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/whatsnew/2021-3/#:%7E:text=,NET%206%20Hot%20Reload%20feature)

[Hot Reload Settings since 2021.3](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/2021.3/Settings_Hot_Reload.html)

[image]

[image]

You need to click 'apply changes' in Rider when you change something:

[image]

By the way, please notice the limitations of the Rider hot reload:

[Limitation of Rider Hot Reload](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Hot_Reload.html#Limitations)

> There are cases when modifying the code is not possible and a restart
> is required. These include changing signatures, modifying generic
> functions, renamings of any kind, and some more. If this happens
> JetBrains Rider will make you aware by showing a tooltip.
>
> Hot Reload is not supported in F# and VB applications.
>
> Hot Reload does not support changes made to the UI formats in
> frameworks like WPF, Windows Forms, and .NET MAUI as well as in Blazor
> WebAssembly (WASM).
>
> When applying Hot Reload to an ASP.NET Core application, the browser
> does not refresh automatically.

**By the way, don't block your thread, otherwise hot reload won't work.**